# Cronjob is firing twice

Tags: cron, cronexpression

So I got the following Cronjob:

```
*/55 * * * * ruby /Users/Supersize/Desktop/test.rb
```

what I expect is, that it fires any `:55`th minute of an hour. Problem: It does the job, but fires another one `5min` after. That means twice per hour with a delay of 5 minutes.

Any idea on this?

Comment: You want it to run at :55 not every 55 minutes. So try replacing `*/55` with `55`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slash (`/`) character is used to specify "every n increments". If you want your trigger fired once an hour at 55 minutes past the hour, your syntax should be:

```
55 * * * * ruby /Users/Supersize/Desktop/test.rb
```